# sysfs cpu information missing

Tags: linux, sysfs

I'm trying to get hold of CPU architecture information under Linux.

I understand the information is available via the sysfs filesystem.

I have CentOS 5 running in a Xen VM.  The sysfs filesystem is mounted.  However, the /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/ directory is almost empty.  The only entry is a single file, "online", with a value of "1".

What gives?  where's all my CPU information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but maybe `/proc/cpuinfo` would help.

Comment: NUMA, cache and logical processor information.  What caches, what arrangement of caches, what processors, how many logical processors, each, etc.  Detailed stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've just had a chat with a sysadmin at work.

Looking at some machines, it looks like this information simply is not pushed by VMs.  The VMs think they have a virtual CPU - rather than a CPU of the type of the real underlying CPU - and the cache information simply is not published.

It is published (and it's nice to finally see it!) on real machines with reasonably modern kernels.

Answer (score 1):

The actual cpu information is still in `/proc/cpuinfo`.

The sysfs-files are used to control things like scheduling and frequency settings, not to get information on the cpus themselves.

Comment: You just beat me by a second :)

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I do not believe this is incorrect.  /proc/cpuinfo contains overall CPU information - it does not contain topology information.  There is nothing about caches and their arrangements.  I have another system, which is at work, which is Redhat under KVM.  This has a /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0 directory which in turns contains a directory called "topology".  This has a little information in - core_id, core_siblings, physical_package_id, thread_siblings - all in read only files - but nothing about caches.  I'm led to understand there should be information about caches here.

Comment: Maybe your kernel is too old? Which version are you using?

Comment: The system at work is 2.6.18-164 - RedHat 5 something.  It's modern enough to have sysfs, I think.  My CentOS system, ironically, is down just right now!